# Selenium, ChromeDriver and diff information

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium and ChromeDriver (with Python) to webscrape some information.

I have a problem, the information it´s diff if I visit with the script (**scraper** ) or I visit with my browser.

Firstly, I think maybe it´s cached information, but I read when I quit driver - driver.quit() - don´t use / close cache.

When I re-run my script the info will be new, ¿no?

Some suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Yes, each time you launch your browser selenium will open without catching, if you want to use the cookies you can preload them as part of browser launch.

Comment: Thanks! I prefer the info will be new when I run the script, but I don´t understand why the info it´s diff if I compare my browser and the script using ChromeDriver.

Comment: Can you provide more info, like what diff you are referring to? Are you pointing to the same url everytime you launch everytime.

Comment: Yes it´s the same URL to browser and driver.get() param. https://url/c?detailRef='+ref+'&flag=-1')